# Python - Library function that given a X,Y pair of point find Xn, Yn which is the closest pair to that pair

Tags: python, numpy, python-itertools

*Disclaimer note: I'm looking for a library, or pre-existing function that accomplishes this. Similar questions ask about the fundamental algorithm where I am looking for a quick implementation. So I apoligize if this appears to be a duplicate question as I'm just looking for a black boxed answer*

Given a pair of geo coordinate points:

```
[34.232,-119.123]
```

And an array of other points:

```
[ [36.232,-117.123], [35.232,-119.123], [33.232,-112.123] ]
```

I'm looking for a function out there that would return a pair from the list above that is closest to the original coordinate

Edited from simple integers to float values

Comment: AFAIK there is no such library. Happy to proven wrong. That said, such a function is about 3-4 lines of code with `scipy.spatial.distance.cdist` and `numpy.argmin`.

Comment: how do you find closest pair?

Comment: @QuangHoang can you provide me as an answer that then since it uses libraries? I don't want to implement a 200 line solution like I see in other answers

Comment: @Jebathon How do you define closest? According to the euclidean distance, the hamming distance, the manhattan ....

Comment: @DaniMesejo I'm going to use an answer here for geocordinates (e.g. I get a longitude, latitude) and for example find the closest city to that point. Instead of X and Y its longitude and latitude.

Comment: @Jebathon you'll want to use the Haversine distance in that case

Comment: @user6386471 Thank you Il look into the Haversine distance

Comment: Use [sklearn's haversine](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.haversine_distances.html) instead of `cdist` in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per comment:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
import numpy as np

def closest(point, ref):
    dist = cdist(ref, [point])
    return ref[np.argmin(dist)]

point = [1,2]
ref = [ [3,1], [4,1], [2,5] ]

closest(point,ref)
# out [3,1]
```

Comment: This is using euclidean by default, right?

Comment: Thank you for your followup

Comment: Yes, by default `cdist` returns euclidean distances.

Answer (score 1):

My two cents:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import euclidean
from functools import partial

key = partial(euclidean, [1,2])

lst = [[3, 1], [4, 1], [2, 5]]
res = min(lst, key=key)
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[3, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

One more:

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KDTree
import numpy as np

X = np.array([[3,1], [4,1], [2,5]])

tree = KDTree(X, leaf_size=2)

dist, ind = tree.query(np.array([1,2]).reshape(1,-1), k=1) 

X[ind][0][0]

# array([3, 1])
```

Answer (score 1):

Using numpy norm for euclidian distance

```
def fun(x, points):
  points = np.array(points)
  return points[np.argmin(np.linalg.norm(points-np.array(x), axis=1))]

print (fun([1,2], [[3,1], [4,1], [2,5]]))
print (fun([1,2], [[3,1], [2,1], [2,5]]))
```

Output:

```
[3 1]
[2 1]
```